# VBA 2次元の動的ジャグ配列

Tags: vba, array

目的：
2次元の動的ジャグ配列を作りたい
2次元目のみを後から拡張したい

1次元配列をvariant形で宣言し、中にまた1次元配列を格納する方針を取りました。
3つの方法を試しましたが、どれもエラーになってしまいました。
正しい方法を教えてください。

方針1：
2次元目を直接redimで拡張する

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr(10) As Variant
    arr(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    redim arr(0)(3)'コンパイルエラー：構文エラー
    arr(0)(4) = 4
End Sub
```

方針2：
1次元目のみを別の配列に渡してから拡張する

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr(10) As Variant
    arr(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Dim arr2
    arr2 = arr
    ReDim arr2(3)
    arr = arr2'コンパイルエラー：配列には割り当てられません
End Sub
```

方針3：
要素の追加を関数化する

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr(10) As Variant
    arr(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Call push(arr(0), 4)'コンパイルエラー：　型が一致しません：配列またはユーザー定義型を指定してください
End Sub

Function push(arr() As Variant, v As Long)
    ReDim arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = v
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「方針２」で良いかと思います。

```
Sub main()

    Dim arr(10) As Variant
    Dim arr2
    
    arr(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    arr2 = arr(0)
    ReDim arr2(3)
    arr(0) = arr2
    
End Sub
```